# How to write a bash script that cuts images into pieces using image magick?

Tags: linux, bash, imagemagick

I have a number of input images that contain multiple smaller images, all of them in a single row. All the contained images are the same size. So, for example, the image `input.png` may be `480x48` and contain 10 `48x48` images, all in one row.

Using the imagemagick `convert` tool (or any other tool supplied with the defaul imagemagick suite), I want to write a bash script that takes an input image, the number of images to cut, and then cuts them all into individual images.

The user interaction i can do, but I've not been able to get `convert` to do the actual cutting. Can anyone suggest something? From reading the manual pages, i think this should work:

`convert 'input.png[0x0+48+48]' output.png`

but I get an error:

> convert: no pixels defined in cache
>   `tb_icons_l.png' @
>   magick/cache.c/OpenCache/3572.
>   convert: No IDATs written into file`
>   1.png' @
>   coders/png.c/PNGErrorHandler/1391.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you've got the position and size swapped. Try:

```
convert 'input.png[48x48+0+0]' output.png
```

The third image would be:

```
convert 'input.png[48x48+96+0]' output.png
```

Or

```
convert 'input.png[48x48+0+96]' output.png
```

Answer (score 9):

I would do it like that:

```
convert input.png -crop 48x48  +repage  +adjoin  output_%02d.gif
```

Read more at [Tile Cropping, in ImageMagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile).